# fetching combination of records using sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query which fetch records

```
1 A
1 P
1 D
1 A
2 A
2 D
2 A
3 A
3 A
3 A
4 A
4 D
4 A
4 D
```

I want to select A and D combination records.
 That is I need to select 
2 A
2 D
2 A
4 A
4 D
4 A
4 D
 but I don't want to select 1 and 3 records
 Could you please help me.

Comment: What should be the output? And which is your database? Sql server, oracle, MySql etc...

Comment: What do you mean A and D combination? Can you show which records from your example should be in output?

Comment: I am using Oracle and the output should be 2 A 2 D 2 A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from yourtable where column1 in 
( 
 select column1
 from yourtable
 group by column1
 having count(distinct column2) = 2 -- Only 2 different values should be possible
 and max(column2) = 'D' 
 and min(column2) = 'A' --Useful if B or C are possible values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * from table where column2_name in ('A','D') and column1_name = 2
```

This will give records that contain A and D.

or

```
Select * from table where column2_name in ('A','D') 
and column1_name = (Select max(column1_name) 
                     from table where column2_name in ('A','D'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (column2 = 'A' OR column2 = 'D') AND MOD(column1, 2) = 0
```